# Loading more entries from database using jquery or ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

PHP

I want to add a 'Load More' Button at the bottom which will display 10 more entries(questions) from the database whenever the user clicks it.

```
<?php include('connection.php');

$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM questions LIMIT 10");

$data = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    $data[] = $row;
}

$number=count($data);
$i=0;
while($i<$number) {  
echo $i+1;
echo ' . ';
echo $data[$i]['question'].'<br/><br/>';
$i++;


?>
```

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: Good start, you probably need to skip the records that have already been shown and sort by something in your query to make it work correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You need a example in jquery+php? Check this out: http://demos.9lessons.info/loadmore.php

And here are the tutorial: http://www.9lessons.info/2009/12/twitter-style-load-more-results-with.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a paging param (such as ?page=2) and use that as your offset.

e.g.

`$offset = $num_per_page * ($page - 1);`

Then change the query to include something like:

... `LIMIT $offset, $num_per_page`

Check the docs [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can set an OFFSET in your query and only load in the new entries

> $query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM questions LIMIT 10 OFFSET =
>   $_POST['offset']");

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to know if there is a need to show the "load more", just select 11 records, show 10 of them and show the "load more" button if the result count is 11